# How to use subselect in MySQL to get all unique names and their count?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I'm trying to make an SQL query, that returns all the unique names and a sum of occurences for each name.

This is what I came up with, but it merely gets the sum of all names and not the sum of each name separately.

```
select distinct(etunimi) as etunimi, 
      (select count(distinct(etunimi)) as määrä from jasenet) 
from jasenet;
```

Is this the right way to go when solving this problem or is there another way of achieving this? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group by a column then aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group and not the complete result set.

```
select etunimi, count(*)
from jasenet
group by etunimi
```

Answer (score 0):

That because you haven't reference the colomn from `outerquery` with `subquery`

So, it should be referenced like that :

```
select distinct etunimi, 
      (select count(*) 
       from jasenet j1
       where j1.etunimi = j.etunimi
      ) as määrä 
from jasenet j;
```

However, i would also suggest to use `GROUP BY` clause which is more efficient than *correlated* `subquery`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how the query would work if done the way I was frist trying to do it.